# Cortex-A5 unaligned access exception

Tags: cortex-a

I have some question for Cortex-A5 unaligned access exception

Basic System information blow

- I and D cache enabled.
- Disabled MMU.
- Firmware base

In developing the DMA driver code I wrote the following C code.

```
UINT32 DMA_InstMOV(UINT8 *buf, tENC_RD rd, UINT32 val)
{
    buf[0] = CMD_DMAMOV;
    buf[1] = rd;
    *((UINT32 *)&buf[2]) = val;         // this line is exception occur
    return SIZE_DMAMOV;
}
```

Dissamber the code above to check them as follows

```
DMA_InstMOV
    0x00000bf8:    e1a03000    .0..    MOV      r3,r0
    0x00000bfc:    e3a000bc    ....    MOV      r0,#0xbc
    0x00000c00:    e5c30000    ....    STRB     r0,[r3,#0]
    0x00000c04:    e5c31001    ....    STRB     r1,[r3,#1]
    0x00000c08:    e5832002    . ..    STR      r2,[r3,#2]
    0x00000c0c:    e3a00006    ....    MOV      r0,#6
    0x00000c10:    e12fff1e    ../.    BX       lr
```

R3 Value is 0x08040000
STR instruction is executed with unaligned address Exception(Data Abort) occurs.
Cortex A5 is not support unaligned access?

In DDI0406C_b_arm_architecture_reference_manual.pdf(Table A3-1 Alignment requirements of load/store instructions)
LDM, STR is not support unaligned access.
So Data Exception occurs.

But I still have some question

1. This drivers code is working good in Cortex-R4 core. It didn’t have any problem.
   Disassebly code is same.
   This is even more confusing
2. Many linux drivers also use the above code.
   If the MMU is turned on, which would solve this problem?

Let’s me know what’s worng for me?

Comment: Can you show some linux driver code where this is done successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable MMU for making an unaligned access in cortex A5. Also make sure the bitfield "A" in SCTLR register is set to 0 to ensure that strict alignment fault is disabled

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you can't do what you are trying if `buf` is 32-bit aligned.

The compiler doesn't know how `buf` is aligned, so it assumes you know what you are doing. If you ask for a 32-bit write (by doing something like `*((UINT32 *)&buf[2])`) then the compilers assumes it is a valid thing to do.  It therefore generates a `STR` instruction, which is only valid for aligned stores.  Hence the fault - as `buf` is 32-bit aligned (as you state), `buf[2]` is clearly not.

I have no idea why the Cortex-R4 experience should be different, as far as I can tell it operates with the same instruction set and alignment rules as the A5 (but I could be wrong).  Maybe you got lucky and your `buf`s were unaligned such that `buf[2]` *was* 32-bit aligned.